# Extending Team Foundation 2010

Tags: tfs

We use TFS 2010 for source control, and have it configured so that team collections can have their own Sharepoint portal.

This works fine and we can create tasks/bugs etc using this.

However we want to extend this into some custom apps that log into our own databases, and TFS.

So bugs can be raised by people outside the normal realm of operation.

My question is, does anyone have or know of some resources that really get under the skin of TFS, all the APi tips and tricks. As well as the more advanced features.

I am happy to buy the books on this, just unsure which books are the right books to buy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Extending Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Already found these, useful for a base, but sadly not very in depth.

Comment: "not very in depth"? That's the documentation on the entire extensibility model. What does it lack?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is a really good starting point, but it does not go into the ins and outs of what is possible, I have found the msdn definitions lacking, in fact I came across an entire obsolete class that said "see ." so I am unsure if they replaced it or just stopped using it.  I just could not find what I was looking for, it is a very good resource, just does not explain things in depth. Marked as correct as this is the official documentation, I was really hoping to find some books though.

Answer (score 2):

I found this set of blog posts by Shai Raiten to be helpful

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/tags/TFS+API/default.aspx

Comment: nice blogs, most for TFS 2008, but still insightful! Thank you